# Develop C with multiple main entry points

Tags: c, entry-point

I used to develop Java project by Eclipse. 
A Java project can contain many code files with the `main` function (the entry point), so we can run each code file which has a `main` function.

But now I want to develop C project by Eclipse CDT.
In a C project we can have only one `main` function.  Can I have many code files with a `main` function and run each file just like I would in Java?

P.S.: I don't like to write *Make Target* for each file by main self

Comment: I'm not posting an answer, because I simply Googled for it: Its a bit clunky - Eclipse does not appear to the the "Solution" concept of Visual Studio: http://tinyguides.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/multiple-binaries-in-single-eclipse-cdt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javas option to have a main in every object is highly irritating and does not make sense to me.

I assume you want to train a bit in c and want to find a way to have all training lessons in one file. Here is an option that would do that for you in a crude way. This would not be reasonable to do as an application but you can use this to execute different options.

To use this you would call your program like 'progname 1'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ProgrammingLesson001(void);


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    int option;
    int e = 0;

    printf("%i\n", argc);

    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }

    if(2 == argc)
    {
        option = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("Your Option was '%s' interpreted as %i\n", argv[1], option);
    }
    else
    {
        option = 0;
        e |= 1;
    }

    switch(option)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("zero is an error\n");
        e |= 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        e |= ProgrammingLesson001();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if(0 != e)
    {
        printf("an error has occureed\n");
    }

    return e;
}

int ProgrammingLesson001(void)
{
    printf("This could behave like a main for training purposes\n");
}
```

If you spent some time programming in c take a second look at makefiles.
You can create a makefile that will fit all your programs.
This reduces the actual work you need to put into this so much that maintaining the switch construct is harder than creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Clifford to fixed my quest and guys who replied

I have solved this problem by myself
Here is my solution:

```
  #!/bin/bash
    SourceFile=$1
    Path="$(dirname "$SourceFile")"
    ParentPath="$(dirname "$Path")"
    OutputPath="$ParentPath/bin"
    OutputFile="$OutputPath/a.out"
    mkdir -p $OutputPath
    rm -f $OutputFile
    gcc -w $SourceFile -lm -o $OutputFile 
    $OutputFile
```

This bash's name is gcc.sh

In eclipse run -> external tools -> external tools configurations -> new a configuration

```
Location: /home/xxxxx/gcc.sh
Working Directory: (just let it be empty)
arguments: ${resource_loc}
```

Then you can run C file by your customize command